# Automation not iterating through list of links yet no errors are thrown

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm creating an automated test with selenium and python and am trying to make it click on each product on a page.  The steps I want to follow are:

1. go to amazon.com.
2. click on search bar.
3. type '3D Printers' into the search bar.
4. click the submit button.
5. click on the first search result.
6. wait 10 seconds.
7. go back to the search results.
8. click on the second search result.
9. etc. etc.

The code I have so far for it goes as follows

```py
# Navigate to the main product page
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/')

# Find Search Bar and enter product to search for
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'twotabsearchtextbox').send_keys('3D Printers')

#Find and click Submit button
driver.find_element(By.ID, "nav-search-submit-button").click()

# Find all the product links on the page
product_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "div[@data-component-type='s-search-result']//a[@class='a-link-normal']")

# Iterate over each product link
for link in product_links:
    print('link', link.text)

    # Click on the product link to go to the product page
    link.click()

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    # Go back to the main product page
    driver.back()

    # Wait for the page to load before finding the next link
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.quit()
```

When I run the test none of the links are clicked yet I don't get any errors after the test completes.  I tried adding a `print()` method to see if I can print the text inside the link but I don't see anything in the console either.  Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your xpath, because it always found zero elements. It  now looks like this: `//span[@class = 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']`

Also, you have to update your list every time you call the driver.back() function, otherwise the items in it get invalid and you will get an exception. I have fixed that by updating the list in the for loop. It should work now.

```
# Navigate to the main product page
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/')

# Find Search Bar and enter product to search for
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'twotabsearchtextbox').send_keys('3D Printers')

#Find and click Submit button
driver.find_element(By.ID, "nav-search-submit-button").click()

# Find all the product links on the page
product_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class = 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']")

print(f"Found {len(product_links)} pages")

# Iterate over each product link
for i, _ in enumerate(product_links):
    print('link', product_links[i].text)

    # Click on the product link to go to the product page
    product_links[i].click()

    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    # Go back to the main product page
    driver.back()
    
    #update the list
    product_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class = 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']")

    # Wait for the page to load before finding the next link
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need all of that code? You simply can add the search query as a parameter in the URL and access the search results directly. For instance, you can use the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) extension to Selenium to get and click the elements. Something like this:

```py
from browserist import Browser

search_query = "3D Printers"

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.open.url(f"https://www.amazon.com/s?k={search_query.replace(' ', '+')}")

    product_links = browser.get.attribute.values("//a[@class='a-link-normal']", "href")

    for link in product_links:
        browser.open.url(link)
```

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist`.

Notes:

- The `https://www.amazon.com/s?k=keywords` is the default search query URL.
- Instead of clicking elements, it's more robust to extract the product link URLs in a list. This is what the `browser.get.attribute.values("//a[@class='a-link-normal']", "href")` part does by targeting relevant `<a>...</a>` tags and getting their `href` link values.
- [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) doesn't need explicit conditions like `WebDriverWait`, `implicitly_wait`, `expected_conditions` or similar – it's already built in so you don't have to worry about it. Instead, [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) awaits an element to be fully loaded before it interacts with it. More on this concept [here](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/#difference-from-selenium).

Here's what I get. I hope this is helpful. Let me know if you have questions?

[image: Browserist web scraper in action]

Answer (score 0):

Another variation using the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) extension of Selenium:

```py
from browserist import Browser

products_xpath = "//span[@class = 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']"

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://www.amazon.com/")
    browser.input.value("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']", "3D Printers")
    browser.click.button("//input[@id='nav-search-submit-button']")

    products_count = browser.tool.count_elements(products_xpath)

    for i in range(1, products_count + 1):
        product_xpath = f"({products_xpath})[{i}]"
        browser.scroll.into_view(product_xpath)
        product_text = browser.get.text(product_xpath)
        print(f"Product {i} of {products_count}: {product_text}")
        browser.click.button(product_xpath)
        browser.back()
```

Notes:

- You need to scroll elements into view before you can interact with them, for instance clicking.
- [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) doesn't need explicit conditions like
  `implicitly_wait` – it's already built in so you don't have to worry about it.

Here's what I get. I hope this is helpful. Let me know if you have questions?

[image: Browserist web scraper in action]